# Where should I put the comma in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> The three main factors of bullying among teenagers are problematic family background, strong desire of power and popularity and influence from mass media.

The number of *and*s in this sentence confuse me, so I don't know where to put the comma. Where should it go?

Comment: The three main factors of bullying among teenagers are problematic family background, strong desire **for** power and popularity, and influence from mass media. I think this is basic English/general reference.

Comment: That's not obvious. What you should do is say it out loud, and when your intonation dips, put a comma. No dip, no comma.

Comment: Could you present it as a bulleted list, rather than as an inline sentence?

Answer (score 1):

@azreen

I would like to use some additional symbols to illustrate why and where commas are used.
See, each of the things in (....) are expressible as one expression, i.e. each of them is a factor, and you are using {, and} operators to list them. Within one such there is a sub-list used as well, in [.!.]. Now it should be clear to you.

The three main factors of bullying among teenagers are: (problematic family background), (strong desire of: [power and popularity]), and (influence from mass media).

Now you can remove the symbols I have added for the sake of understanding, and use only commas.

I have assumed very basic logical common sense, and no deep knowledge of English. You may find certain conventions of using English sometimes weird, but most of the times, while learning, you will feel, it is really common sense that drives the language most of the times, rather than any list of rules and regulations.

Comment: @azreen hey, if you liked this approach of answering a question, you should pick this as the correct answer as per your choice! :)

Answer (score -1):

The comma should go after popularity. The reason why is that both power and popularity are the "strong desires", so influence from mass media is a different factor.